# Компонент на GridBagLayout растягивается и сжимает остальные

Tags: java, gui, layout, jframe

Добавляю компоненты прямо на форму.

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

frame.add(scrollPane, new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,3,5.0,5.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0,0));
frame.add(replaceArea, new GridBagConstraints(1,0,1,1,1.0,1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0,0));
frame.add(ignoredReplaceArea, new GridBagConstraints(1,1,1,1,1.0,1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0,0));
frame.add(countLetter, new GridBagConstraints(1,2,1,1,1.0,0.2, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0,0));
frame.add(okButton, new GridBagConstraints(0,3,2,1,0.2,1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0,0));
```

Если начать писать, то `JTextArea` сжимается и растягивается (Причем при четном кол-ве символов расширяется, при нечетном сжимается, если ввести три символа, то будет как на первой картинке, только по ширине этих 3 символов)

[image: Один символ]
[image: Два]
[image: Три]
[image: МНОГО]

Как зафиксировать сетку?